# Pandas DataFrame + Count number of items in column by boolean on other

Tags: python

There must be a simply way of doing this...  I have a dataframe that looks like:

```
STRIKE  TOTAL OI    CALLPUT
95      1035           P
95.125  500            C
95.25   550            C
```

I am trying to sum "TOTAL OI" where CALLPUT == "C".  So answer should be 1050.

Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you do a simple `groupby`? `df_callput = df.groupby(by = "CALLPUT").sum()`. Then your result will be in `df_callput.loc["C"]`.

Comment: that.... is too easy.  thanks Mikk

Answer (score 2):

This is the type of thing `groupby` is for (http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html).

Assuming your dataframe is in `df`:

```
df_callput = df.groupby(by = "CALLPUT").sum()
df_callput.loc["C"]["CALLPUT"]
```